# JProfiler: How to load agent library?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jprofiler

I'm trying to run jpenable on a standard java application in our remote server but I'm getting an error saying that:

**ERROR: The agent could not be loaded: Failed to load agent library**

Server OS:
Linux debian-server 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sat Mar 31 04:00:05 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

System variables:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/dev/jprofiler7/bin/linux-x64"
PATH="/home/dev/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/java/default/bin:/home/dev/jprofiler7/bin/linux-x64"
```

Java options:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true "
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$HOME/keystorage/cacerts.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=$CACERTS_PASSWORD"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should only contain the path not the file. Try it with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/dev/jprofiler7/bin/linux-x64`. Please also post the command line you are using to start Java.

Comment: Updated LD_LIBRARY_PATH and added Java options

Comment: Are you specifying these variables for jpenable? jpenable does not need any such variables. For Java 1.5+, you never need to modify LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Is JAVA_OPTS an environment variable that is used by your server start script? I think you're mixing two strategies here, jpenable is for profiling an already running JVM, adding an -agentpath VM parameter in the start script loads the profiling agent and jpenable is not required.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a start script for the app. I separated the option for agentpath so I can easily enable/disable. I tried running using both methods: (1)Disabling the agentpath option and running jpenable which gave me this error and (2)Enabling the agentpath option and starting the app which makes my app crash.

I'm removing the agentpath for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work. Problem was that the server machine uses 32-bit Java even if it's running 64-bit OS. I also had to download ia32-libs as I had missing dependencies as well.

There was also no need to modify/add LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH.